# Complex object in grid view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, gridview, lazy-loading

I have a gridview, the datasource of which is the following function:

```
public static List<Train> GetTrainsByIDs(int [] ids) {
    using (var context = new MyEntities()) 
    {
        return ids.Select(x => context.Trains.Single(y => y.TrainID ==x)).AsQueryable().Include(x=>x.Station).ToList();
    }
}
```

The grid view has an ItemTemplate of `<%# Eval("Station.Name") %>`.
This causes the error `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection` despite the fact that I used the include method.

When I change the function to

```
public static List<Train> GetTrainsByIDs(int [] ids) {
    using (var context = new MyEntities()) 
    {
        return context.Trains.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.TrainID)).Include(x=>x.Station).ToList();
    }
}
```

it works fine, but then they come out in the wrong order, and also if I have 2 ids the same I would like 2 identical trains in the list.

Is there anything I can do other than create a new viewmodel? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @Gert Arnold's answer, and getting the idea of doing it in 2 stages, I managed  very simply using the first query like this:

```
using (context = new MyEntities())
{
    var trns = context.Trains.Include(x => x.Station);
    return ids.Select(x => trns.Single(y => y.TrainID == x)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the first query: that's deferred execution.You created an `IEnumerable` of `Train`s, noticed that it did not have the `Include` method, so cast it to `IQueryable`, added the Include and added the `ToList()` to prevent lazy loading.

But As per [MSDN on DbExtensions.Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

> This extension method calls the Include(String) method of the IQueryable source object, if such a method exists. If the source IQueryable does not have a matching method, *then this method does nothing.*

(emphasis mine)

The result of the select is an `IEnumerable` converted to `IQueryable`, but now implemented by [`EnumerableQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerablequery%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which does not implement `Include`. And nothing happens.

Now the data enters the grid which tries to display the station, which triggers lazy loading while the context is gone.

Apart from that, this design has another flaw: it fires a query for each id separately.

So the second query is much better. It is one query, including the `Station`s. But now the order is dictated by the order the database pleases to return. You could use `Concat` to solve this:

```
IQueryable<Train> qbase = context.Trains.Include(x=>x.Station);
IQueryable<Train> q = null;

foreach (var id in ids)
{
  var id1 = id; // Prevent modified closure.
  if (q == null)
    q = qbase.Where(t => t.Id == id1);
  else
    q = q.Concat(qbase.Where (t => t.Id == id1));
}
```

The generated query is not very elegant (to say the least) but after all it is one query as opposed to many.

Comment: I _want_ duplicates - I wrote **I would like 2 identical trains in the list**. And the order is vital - the list of ids represent the list of trains in the person's journey, and a journey has to be taken in the right order. What I had to do was remove the 'using' and rely on garbage collection.

Comment: Yes, sorry, your question was clear, my head wasn't. I've modified the answer concerning the second query. The analysis of the first query stands. I would go for a scenario where the context is explicitly disposed.